# iPhone/iPad context menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Im talking about the menu that shows up when you select a block of text it gives you the option to cut/paste/copy. I figured out how to add one more option to the menu, but if I add two or more options it will say "more" first. clicking it will show all the options I added. But is there a way to show all the options I added upfront? without the "more" menu item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html).  If you don't want Copy/Paste/Cut, you'll include something like this in your `canPerformAction:` method:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
     if(action == @selector(someSelector:))
         return YES;
     else 
         return NO;
}
```

Creating a new menu item looks like this:

```
UIMenuItem *someAction = [[UIMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Something" action:@selector(doSomething:)];

UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
menu.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:someAction];
[menu update];
```

Comment: It's not that I don't want those. I need to add two more menu items.

Comment: Then you still use something like I posted but rather then doing @selector(copy:), change it to something like @selector(copyText:), then implement your own - (void)copyText method that does the copying.  Then your other items won't get pushed to the more menu.

Comment: can I change the text of the menu item?

Comment: Yes, you do that by creating custom UIMenuItems- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume your talking about [`UIMenuController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html). If you don't want to see Copy/Paste/Cut/Delete/Select/SelectAll you will need to add the following code to your `UITextField`'s or `UITextView`'s delegate:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction: (SEL)action withSender: (id)sender {
    BOOL answer = NO;
    if (action == @selector(item1)) {
        answer = YES;
    }
    if (action == @selector(item2)) {
        answer = YES;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Where `item1` and `item2` are the names of the objects in `UIMenuController.menuItems`.

In my experience if you are using a `UITextView` the Copy, Paste, Cut and Select All menu items will remain, in this case add the following code to a subclass of `UITextView`.

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(cut:) || action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(selectAll:)) {
            return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to disable those options, I need to add two more custom options.