# how to show options when a user clicks on UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios4

[image]

I am showing records in a UITableView having UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton as the cell accessory. I want to display these "Save","Send to" and "Visit" options when user click on detail disclosure button, but i have no idea how to do this.
Please help me.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833184/iphone-ipad-context-menu

Comment: please post it as an answer and let me accept it. :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first, you have to implement (this is different call from particular select row)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

inside it, you're using some code like this:

```
        UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        AddRouteMenuItem *menuItem = [[AddRouteMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add to push list" action:@selector(addRouteMenuButtonPressed:)];
        menuItem.indexPath = pressedIndexPath;
        menuController.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem];
        [menuItem release];
        [menuController setTargetRect:[self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:pressedIndexPath] inView:self.tableView];
        [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

You pressed index path = indexPath

last point - is a change pointer to accessory button
- (void)setTargetRect:(CGRect)targetRect inView:(UIView *)targetView