# show UIMenuController under UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

How to show UIMenuController under UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton when click it?

There is a answer code on [how to show options when a user clicks on UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657818/how-to-show-options-when-a-user-clicks-on-uitableviewcellaccessorydetaildisclosu),
but it don't have "AddRouteMenuItem", does someone know?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)clickOnDetailDisclosureButton
{
   UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuController setTargetRect:[self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:pressedIndexPath] inView:self.tableView];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```