# Phonegap/iOS — Disable popup menu for selected text

Tags: ios, cordova

I have used -webkit-user-select to limit selections to text, and now I'd like to prevent iOS from popping up the default menu that comes with text selections. In other words, I want users to be able to select text, but I don't want the copy/define menu to show up. Either that, or I'd like to be able to modify that menu with my own options. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this answer: [iPhone/iPad context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833184/iphone-ipad-context-menu)

You will probably need to either hack the PhoneGap source and recompile the framework or write a plugin to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, a plugin is necessary. Sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try disable native callout with this css property:

```css
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```