# Right-click MenuIcon

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How would I make it so that when the user right-clicks, control-clicks or command-clicks on the menu item have it show a menu but if they just click do an action

What I would like it to do is similar to Caffeine:
[Caffeine](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12)

Comment: 'menu item' could be interpreted in many ways. Could you edit your question to include the code where you're adding the item to the menu please?

Comment: I found a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833184/iphone-ipad-context-menu) that looks like it might help resolve your issue

Answer (score -1):

Can create mouse Event and add Options there as required. For more Details Search http://net4attack.blogspot.com/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Dear user806084, I didn't see anything relevant to this question. could you please give more information or give some piece of code to help other?